# How to create cairo surface in guile

Tags: scheme, cairo, guile

I have this code

```
guile> (cairo-pdf-surface-create "foo.pdf" 100.0 100.0)
; and get this error
standard input:29:1: In procedure cairo-pdf-surface-create in expression (cairo-pdf-surface-create "foo.pdf" 100.0 ...):
standard input:29:1: Wrong type (expecting string): 100.0
ABORT: (wrong-type-arg)
```

and when I use strings as width and height

```
guile> (cairo-pdf-surface-create "foo.pdf" "100.0" "100.0")

Backtrace:
In standard input:
  30: 0* [cairo-pdf-surface-create "foo.pdf" {"100.0"} "100.0"]

standard input:30:1: In procedure cairo-pdf-surface-create in expression (cairo-pdf-surface-create "foo.pdf" "100.0" ...):
standard input:30:1: Wrong type (expecting real number): "100.0"
```

Documentation says:

> cairo-pdf-surface-create (filename <char>)                                 [Function]
>            (width-in-points
>   <double>) (height-in-points <double>)
>            ⇒ (ret <cairo-surface-t>)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least for the most recent version, try this:

```
(cairo-pdf-surface-create 100.0 100.0 "foo.pdf")
```

See [the source](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~andywingo/guile-cairo/trunk/annotate/head%3A/guile-cairo/guile-cairo.c), which specifies the arguments in the order `(sx sy filename)`, with the filename being optional (using the current output port if not specified).

Comment: At the maintainer's request (I verified this answer with him on IRC), I've filed a bug for the documentation: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=30510